# Rewrite URL: remove second part of url

Tags: .htaccess

I am new to htaccess, I am facing issue. 
I have following url:

```
example.com/booking/tickets
```

I want the following output

```
example.com/tickets
```

This is my .htacess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule booking/tickets http://example.com/tickets/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Problem is page is redirecting to the booking page, I want to call the booking/tickets page and url should rewrite "booking/tickets" to "tickets". So how to achieve this. I need help
Thanks in advance

Comment: anubhava : yes booking is a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rewrite the url, remove the hostname from  rewrite target

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^booking/tickets/?$ /tickets/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: There is no `$1` here